# How to Use Config Based Connection in Laravel Package

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am developing my custom package in Laravel, and I need users to be able to set the connection for the package models based on configuration.

I cant do:

```
protected $connection = Config::get('billing.connection');
```

because expressions are not allowed as field default values.

When doing

```
public function getConnection()
{
    return Config::get('billing.connection'); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

It says `Call to a member function getQueryGrammar() on a string.` Is there any other way I can allow the users to set the database connection for my packages models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override other method for this. Instead of

```
public function getConnection()
{
    return Config::get('billing.connection'); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

you should use

```
public function getConnectionName()
{
    return Config::get('billing.connection'); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```